# Apache isn't deflating my website home page

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, gzip, mod-deflate

I have the following 3 rules at /.htaccess

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
```

All of those mime types get served deflated except website home page which is text/html...
Website: poker10.com

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can answer your question and accept it later. See this blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment before, the problem was in PHP.

Comment: Can you provide some information that might help the next person to encounter this problem (**What** was the problem? **How* did you fix it?)?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php 
your 2 index pages www.poker10.com/index.html and poker10.com/index.php are served gzip.
So for now I do not see where is the problem ?

In case you need to conserve some resources on your server I suggest to stop using .htaccess file and move it's content in the main config file.

Comment: Well, I have fixed the problem in the meanwhile. That's why they are gzipped now. The problem was in php zlib library, but I didn't know how to close this question. ):